# How do I uncompress a mysql table once its been compressed using ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

Tags: mysql, compression

If I create a mysql table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `testing` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
```

But then I decide I no longer want it compressed, how do I go about decompressing it? I assume its something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE testing ROW_FORMAT=SOMETHING
```

But my Googlefu has failed to find what the value of `SOMETHING` should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ALTER TABLE testing ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;`

This is mentioned in MySQL Reference Manual in [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) -syntax section.